# What is repetition in ANOVA?

Tags: anova, terminology, independence, intuition

I came across an explanation [here](https://www.statisticshowto.datasciencecentral.com/probability-and-statistics/hypothesis-testing/anova/), which states

> It’s whether you are replicating (i.e. duplicating) your test(s) with multiple groups. With a two way ANOVA with replication , you have two groups and individuals within that group are doing more than one thing (i.e. two groups of students from two colleges taking two tests). If you only have one group taking two tests, you would use without replication.

My confusion is as follows,

1. what is being repeated?
2. is test and treatment the same?
3. In the statement above: "two groups of students from two colleges taking two tests", what are the 2 independent variables?
4. How does "If you only have one group taking two tests, you would use without replication."  indicate 2-way ANOVA without repetition?

I am confused about what is being conveyed in the above statement, perhaps due to the terminology that I am unaware of, or my comprehension of the repetition idea.

Any help with real-world examples, explaining the concept of repetition is much appreciated!